# How to create a time picker dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

My `timepicker` dropdown is not working.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timepicker-input').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    minTime: '10',
    maxTime: '6:00pm',
    defaultTime: '11',
    startTime: '10:00',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
  });
});
```

Comment: show you html code also, i.e element with class name 'timepicker-input'

Answer (score 2):

use this library for time picker
http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/

```
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/persian.datepicker.css"/>
       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="js/persian.date.js"></script>
       <script src="js/persian.datepicker.js"></script>
   </head>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".example1").pDatepicker();
     });
   </script>

  <input type="text" class="example1" />
```

Comment: This answer is apt, however it would be much more helpful to future users of Stack Overflow, if you could also add an explanation why this answer works. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me, I disabled the time format because it will ruin the rendering of time:

```
<input type="text" id="timepicker-input" placeholder="00:00" />
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#timepicker-input').timepicker({
    //timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    minTime: '10',
    maxTime: '6:00pm',
    defaultTime: '11:00am',
    startTime: '10:00am',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
  });
});
```